# How to replace function that works with id to classname

Tags: javascript

This is a continuation of my previous question ([Multiple date selection events to assign a value to an input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56261439/multiple-date-selection-events-to-assign-a-value-to-an-input-field)) and made some progression. I managed to partially solve the issue, and this is working only for one when I am using the document.getElementById. I know as IDs must be different to work for both, and therefore I am trying to use ClassName. And here I got studk. I am struggling to make it work for the arrays using the ClassName. Any help will be highly appreciated. below is the one working for ID.

```
<table class='table' id="tb_actions">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="text-center" > Due </th>
<th class="text-center" > Date Complete </th>
<th class="text-center" > Overdue </th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr>
<td><input type="date" name="dt_due[]" id="datedue" class="form-control" /></td>
<td><input type="date" name="dt_complete[]" id="datecomplete" class="form-control"  /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="overdue[]" id="overdue" class="form-control" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="date" name="dt_due[]" id="datedue" class="form-control" /></td>
<td><input type="date" name="dt_complete[]" id="datecomplete" class="datecomplete form-control" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="overdue[]" id="overdue" class="form-control" /></td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>

<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>


<script>

const d1 = document.getElementById("datedue");
const d2 = document.getElementById("datecomplete");
const od = document.getElementById("overdue");

$("#datecomplete").on("change", function () {
 var dd1 = new Date($('#datedue').val());
 var dd2 = new Date($('#datecomplete').val());

document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = dd1
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = dd2

    if( dd2 > dd1){
     od.value = 'Yes';
     od.style.color = 'red'
     } else {
     od.value = 'No';
     od.style.color = 'blue'
    }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: You will need to use `$(this).closest("tr")` to climb up to the table row, then `.find(".classNameHere")` to get the appropriate elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this as below, [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6asbcofu/)

```
<table class='table' id="tb_actions">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="text-center" > Due </th>
<th class="text-center" > Date Complete </th>
<th class="text-center" > Overdue </th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr>
<td><input type="date" name="dt_due[]" id="datedue" class="form-control" /></td>
<td><input type="date" name="dt_complete[]" id="datecomplete" class="form-control datecomplete"  /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="overdue[]" id="overdue" class="form-control" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="date" name="dt_due[]" id="datedue" class="form-control" /></td>
<td><input type="date" name="dt_complete[]" id="datecomplete" class="datecomplete form-control" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="overdue[]" id="overdue" class="form-control" /></td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>

<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>

<script>
  $(".datecomplete").on("change", function () {
     var parent = $(this).closest("tr");
   var dd1 = new Date(parent.find('#datedue').val());
   var dd2 = new Date(parent.find('#datecomplete').val());
   var od = parent.find('#overdue');

   document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = dd1
   document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = dd2

    if( dd2 > dd1){
       $(od).val('Yes');
       $(od).css('color', 'red')
     } else {
       $(od).val('No');
       $(od).css('color', 'blue')
     }
});
</script>
```